# Geometry of Intersection Between Elements

Tags: revit-api

My goal is to intersect a duct with a wall, then getting the geometry of the intersection and get its dimensions so I can make a sleeve Automatically.
I tried the workflow in dynamo and it worked through intersecting the solid of each element then getting the "Cuboid" of the Intersection and getting its dimensions and so on.
the problem is, i can't find anything in the Revit API Docs that will get me the shape and geometry of the intersection.

Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Revit API, you can use the [`Element.Geometry` property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/d8a55a5b-2a69-d5ab-3e1f-6cf1ee43c8ec.htm) to retrieve the element geometry and the solids it contains. With those in hand, you can determine the intersection using the [`BooleanOperationsUtils.ExecuteBooleanOperation` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/89cb7975-cc76-65ba-b996-bcb78d12161a.htm).

Comment: I will try that and get back to you with the results.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly.
You are always backing us up.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation! My pleasure entirely. :-)